# Excepetion error occurs onOptionsItemSelected by using SherlockActivity

Tags: java, android

I just want to create a simple go back(home)button but I got the following errors

```
e(12674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 15:38:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(12674): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity DevicesActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)
06-11 15:38:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(12674):    at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NavUtils.java:74)
06-11 15:38:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(12674):    at com.example.wip.DevicesActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DevicesActivity.java:252)
06-11 15:38:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(12674):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockExpandableListActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockExpandableListActivity.java:197)
06-11 15:38:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(12674):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:603)
```

My codes:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Manifest

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.project.project1.MainActivity"
            android:label="Project1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.project.project1.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
            android:parentActivityName="com.project.wip.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
```

Also Can I do something like this? The code works. anything bad about the following code?

```
    case android.R.id.home:
    Intent intent = new Intent(secondActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
    return true;
```

Comment: There is already a "back" button on the android device itself. Any reason you want another?

Comment: What do you mean by there is already a "back" button? I only need one, but it doesn't work. Intent intent = new Intent(secondActivity.this,MainActivity.class); this is workaround I'm thinking if I cannot fix the exception error.

Comment: Every Android device has a "back" button on the phone itself. It's what they call a "hard button". When you are looking at the phone, it is the arrow, generally on the left.

Comment: I see, but the back arrow only works if I have onCreateOptionsMenu method working. Isn't?

Comment: No. This button is independent of the application; it is independent of all applications. Most phones use to have it directly on the phones, but now that all the phones have huge screens, they have moved the hard buttons onto the screen.

Comment: Well. If I delete the codes, there is no arrow and doesn't respond anything if i click the title bar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31599/discussion-between-blaine-and-michael)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the fact that you don't have the following code in your manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
```

Chances are you are using a device that isn't ICS, which is why it isn't working.

There is nothing wrong with the code you have at the bottom, but I would put it into a menu like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            ...
    case android.R.id.home:
    Intent intent = new Intent(secondActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      ....

    return true;
}
```

This will lay the foundation for you to add buttons to go to other area's, as well as home.